# Google Analytics API: get total events per day/week

Tags: google-analytics

For example, I use this query to get the total events in a specific time interval:

`https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=<redacted>&start-date=2019-01-01&end-date=today&metrics=ga%3AtotalEvents&dimensions=ga%3AeventLabel&filters=ga%3AeventLabel%3D%3D<some value>`

How can I get the events per day in that time interval? Is there any other way instead of making a request for each day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add `ga:date` dimension in the query to split data by days.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think it would be that easy. Thanks!